# wx.EVT_MAXIMIZE prevented exiting full screen

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a frame with one radio box to toggle full screen. The frame is to go full screen when the user clicks the Maximize button. However, if I use the maximize button,  the radio box would then fail to restore the window. If I use the radio box to go full screen, it will be able to restore the window.

```
import wx


class FSWindow(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  self.SetSize((800, 600))
  self.RadioFullScreen = wx.RadioBox(self, -1, "Display", choices=["Windowed","Full Screen"])
  self.RadioFullScreen.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBOX, self.FS)
  self.Bind(wx.EVT_MAXIMIZE, self.OnMaximize)
  self.Sizer = None
  self.Show()

def FS(self, Event):
  if self.RadioFullScreen.GetSelection():
    self.ShowFullScreen(True)
  else:
    self.ShowFullScreen(False)

def OnMaximize(self, Event):
  self.ShowFullScreen(True) # <-- Add self.Restore() or self.Maximize(False) here
  self.RadioFullScreen.SetSelection(1)


App = wx.App()
frame =FSWindow(None, -1, "MainWindow")
App.MainLoop()
```

However, if I add self.Restore() or self.Maximize(False) before the self.ShowFullScreen(True) like I commented on the source code above, the radio buttons will work. Problem is, the window will be restored first before going full screen which is ugly. Any solution for this? Also please explain why this happened, if possible.

Running Python 2.7.9, WxPython 3.0.2 on Window 7 Professional 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ShowFullScreen is not setting some flag, so things get out of sync.

If I just use Maximize/Restore things work fine for me, i.e. following changes to your code.

```
def FS(self, Event):
    if self.RadioFullScreen.GetSelection():
        self.Maximize()
        #self.ShowFullScreen(True, style=wx.FULLSCREEN_ALL)
        print('done fs true')
    else:
        #self.ShowFullScreen(False, style=wx.FULLSCREEN_ALL)
        self.Restore()
        print('done fs false')


def OnMaximize(self, Event):
    Event.Skip()
    self.RadioFullScreen.SetSelection(1)
    print('done max')
```

If you don't want the menu bar etc when the screen is maximized then uncomment the ShowFullScreen lines.

You are handling an event "Maximize", most of the time you want default behaviour also to happen, that is why I added Event.Skip to the OnMaximize handler - in this case it doesn't make a difference as it looks like the event is only fired after maximisation is already done.